# Setting a value in an array in obj-c

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsarray

I know this is a really simple thing in obj-c, but I can't seem to find anywhere (on here or google) how to do this. Basically I just want to replace one array value (the value is a NSString) with another, so something like this...

```
[sharedInstance.groundMap objectAtIndex:ii] = myImage;
```

But I get an error expression is not assignable. I also tried...

```
[[sharedInstance.groundMap objectAtIndex:ii] setValue:(NSString*) myImage];
```

But that gives an error too.

Comment: Really Phil, you couldn't find it anywhere? How about the NSMutableArray Class Reference? I don't understand why so many people look for answers on google or SO, you should go to the Apple docs first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to be using an `NSMutableArray` to set a value. Use the `replaceObjectAtIndex:withObject:` method or use the new Objective-C syntax:

```
[sharedInstance.groundMap replaceObjecAtIndex:ii withObject:myImage];
```

or

```
sharedInstance.groundMap[ii] = myImage;
```

Neither works with `NSArray`. Only `NSMutableArray`.

Answer (score 2):

First, your array needs to be *mutable* (i.e. an instance of `NSMutableArray`, not simply `NSArray`). With `NSMutableArray` you can do this:

```
[sharedInstance.groundMap replaceObjectAtIndex:ii withObject:myImage];
```

If you have the latest Xcode, you can use the `array[index] = value` syntax as well.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you might want

```
[sharedInstance.groundMap replaceObjectAtIndex:11 withObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"test"]];
```

Comment: Why are you using `stringWithFormat:` for a string literal with no formatting?

Comment: it just part of the code i use before

since your `myImage` is an NSString you can use it directly as @maddy and @dasblinkenlight suggested